# How to deal with unknown character encodings returned in requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been working with the YouTube API, but have had some issues with characters not in the character encoding set crashing the program. I originally tried encoding the string with `.encode('utf-8')`, but even still, certain characters still crash the program. For example, `♬`. This will cause a crash when used in the program.

```
getVid = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + vidQuery + '&key=' + self.ytApiKey + '&type=video')
  vidData = json.load(getVid)
  vidId = vidData["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]
  if not vidId:
    self.say(target2 + ': Unable to find a video for that query.', target)
  else:
    vidTitle = vidData["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"].encode('utf-8')
    self.say(target2 + ': The song ' + vidTitle + 'has been requested.', target)
```

Specifically, the error occurs when attempting to use `vidTitle` in the response, or possibly when attempting to save it to the variable.

Is there another character encoding that supports more extended characters? Or is there a way to dynamically change the character encoding? Or worst case scenario, strip any characters outside of the character encoding?

Comment: add the code that is causing the error

Comment: What are you doing with the string?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm sending it as an IRC message. (The code is a Twitch.tv IRC client)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham One of the specific strings that was crashing the client was "♬ Midna's Desperate Hour (cover)", with the data returned from the YouTube API.

Comment: have you tried `'♬'.decode("utf-8").encode("utf-8")`?

Comment: the crash is encoding related?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes. The exact error name is `UnicodeEncodeError`. Even using `.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8)` still produces this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u266c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. U+266C is the beamed 16th note.

Comment: where are you running this from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm running it from the terminal on a VPS running 14.04.02 LTS with Python 2.7.6

Comment: so from a python shell `print u'♬'.encode("utf-8")` gives you the same error?

Comment: I attempted that, but putting that character in via console is proving to be problematic, since it doesn't actually show up, and just appears to move the cursor in the terminal, and won't actually print it out.

Comment: what does `locale` output from bash?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: ok,  try  `sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` or whatever is relevant then try to encode again, you might need to reboot. Also check that the locale output now differs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Unfortunately, it still doesn't allow me to enter the character. However, I whipped up a test script: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wz5AtdDf And it seems to work.

Comment: what does locale output now?

Comment: For some reason, locale didn't change.